# How to find the number of possible functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations, combinations

Let A be a set with 10 elements, B be a set with 2 elements, and C be a set with 5 elements. Let f be any function from A to B, and g be a function from B to C. Let h(x) = g(f(x)) = (f(g(x)). How many different h(x) function exists? I really do not get why the answer is C(5,2)*(2^10 − 2) + 5 = 10225
Also look at:https://oeis.org/A181162

Comment: Did you mean $g(f(x))=(g ∘ f)(x)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes ı meant g(f(x)) = (f(g(x)) @SweepingBishops

Comment: To be clear... $g(f(x))=(f(g(x)))$ has to be wrong.  $(g\circ f)(x)$ is in some conventions interpreted as $g(f(x))$ and in other interpretations interpreted as $f(g(x))$.  Even without the question for clarification from SweepingBishops, it was clear that it must be that $h(x)=g(f(x))$, not only from the original question staement, but because the output of $f(x)$ is an element of $B$ and the input of $g$ must also be an element of $B$.  It makes no sense to talk about $f(g(x))$ here since the sets don't line up.  The only possible confusion is how you prefer to notate with $\circ$.

Comment: Now... that is not $210$, that should be $2^{10}=1024$... very different.  Be careful when copy pasting and losing formatting.  You should type things with [MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Now... for counting... break into cases based on if everything mapped to a single element, or if things mapped to two different elements.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I never knew that in some conventions $(g∘f)(x)=f(g(x))$; learn something new everyday I guess :)

Comment: Sorry about the things that caused misunderstanding I edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $h=g\circ f$ (*or $h=f\circ g$ depending on your preference for notation...*) and since $|B|=2$, it follows that either everything gets mapped to the same thing by $h$ or everything gets mapped to one of two things by $h$.  Make sure you can understand why.

Suppose everything got mapped to the same thing by $h$, i.e. $h$ is a constant function.  Pick what that one thing is that they mapped to.  There are $5$ options.

Stop here and make sure you understand that we are merely counting the number of possible functions $h$.  We are *not* counting how many choices of $f$ and $g$ there are.  Certain different choices of $f$ and $g$ will result in the same $h$.  For trivial example... letting $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,10\},B=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{1,2,\dots,5\}$ we could have had $f$ was the constant function $A\to B$ mapping everything to $2$ and $g$ the constant function $B\to C$ mapping everything to $3$... thus making $h$ the constant function $A\to C$ mapping everything to $3$.  Similarly, if $f$ were anything else and $g$ still the constant mapping everything to $3$, you still have $h$ is the constant mapping everything to $3$.  That is not a sufficiently different outcome here and those count as the same $h$.

---

Now... counting the other case, two things get mapped to.  Pick what two things those were in the codomain of $C$ that are being mapped to.  There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ such ways to choose those two things.

Next, choose which *nonempty strict subset* of $A$ gets mapped to the smaller of the two things picked from $C$.  There are $2^{10}$ subsets of $A$... one of which is empty, and one of which is the entirety of $A$ itself, neither of which could be picked here.  So, there are $2^{10}-2$ choices for what nonempty strict subset to map to the smaller of the choices picked from $C$.  The remaining elements not picked from $A$ will all map to the other choice picked from $C$.

This gives:

$$\binom{5}{2}\times \left(2^{10}-2\right)+5$$

Comment: I completely understood first part (why I should not count how many choices f and g are there) but I still have questions about second part. Why I am selecting 2 elements from C if it is because of g is a function from B to C why we taking all subsets of A should not we take 5 elements from A because g is from B to C?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that question since it seems so natural and obvious to me.  $f$ can be thought of as "compressing information" here, since there are only two possible outputs for $f$.  Think of $B$ as $\{\text{top},\text{bottom}\}$ and picture the overall map $A\to B\to C$ and remember that there is *only one* arrow possible leaving the top of $B$, and *only one* arrow possible leaving the bottom of $B$.  Only two things at most can be pointed to in $C$ by these arrows, one pointed to from the top of $B$, the other being pointed to from the bottom of $B$.

Comment: I understand that now. Because of B has 2 only element it can only go to 2 places at C so I calculate C(5,2). But I am asking why I do not do this at A since f(g(x)) starts from B(This could be such a stupid question)

Comment: But we aren't doing $f(g(x))$.  We are doing $g(f(x))$.  The overall map (*with keeping track of distractions*) goes $A\to B\to C$.  $h$ is a map from $A\to C$

Comment: But isn't h(x) = g(f(x)) = (f(g(x)) .

Comment: $h(x)$ is $g(f(x))$.  Period.  Full stop.  This is not $f(g(x))$, that is something different.  That, if it were able to be defined properly would have gone $B\to A\to C$.  (*which it wouldn't barring some annoying conditions on $A,B,C$ since it was stated earlier that $f$ goes from $A\to B$ and $g$ goes from $B\to C$*)

Comment: So you are saying C(5,2)×(2^10−2)+5 is the answer of how many different g(f(x)) function exists.

Comment: Yes, with the understanding that we care about the final result of the functions, and do not care about what happened on the way to the final result.

Comment: Then the answer of (How many different g(f(x)) function exists) and the answer of (How many different f(g(x)) function exists) are same because we do not care about the domain and between we only care about the codomain.

Comment: The question of how many different $f(g(x))$ functions exist is ill-posed and nonsensical.  There is no reason to expect $f(g(x))$ to be valid.  As an example... let $A=\{\text{Adam, Barbara, Charles,...}\}$ and let $B=\{\text{apple, banana}\}$ and $C=\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$.  Let $f~:~A\to B$ be the function that maps a person to their favorite fruit, and let $g~:~B\to C$ be the number of that fruit available in my pantry.  So... $g(f(x))=h(x)$ is the number of fruit in the pantry that the named person likes...  $g(f(\text{Adam}))$ could be $g(\text{apple})$ could be $5$...

Comment: Meanwhile... if you try to talk about $f(g(\text{Adam}))$... how many Adams do I have in my pantry?  What is the favorite fruit of $5$?  Those don't make any sense

Comment: I see I think the question is wrong about the (h(x) = g(f(x)) = (f(g(x))) part because that is not valid. Thank you very much for your help.